# Stop QProgressDialog from making dock icon bounce

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

I have a function in my application that calls various subfunctions depending on the configuration. Each sub function is computationally intensive so I added a callback to update the status of a modal QProgressDialog. Each subfunction shows 0-100% completion of itself rather than the parent function.

If the dialog closes between subfunctions and the window doesn't have focus, the dock icon bounces. This can be seriously annoying if there are more subfunctions remaining as the user has switched focus away for a reason!

Is there a way to disable icon bouncing for when a QProgressDialog closes without focus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `QProgressDialog::setAutoClose(false)` the progress dialog will stay open between the subfunctions and stop the dock icon from bouncing.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, the scenario you describe (even if working "correctly") leads to one of my pet peeves.  That is: a progress bar which gets to the end, *and then starts over at 0%*.  I'd rather a piece of software just say "working..." than give me an intentionally misleading progress bar!!

Why not divide your progress bar into phases, and then allocate each subfunction a section of the progress bar?  In the simplest case, if you had two phases that were equal in duration you would let the first phase go from 0 to 50, and then the second phase from 50 to 100.  This way you only put up and take down the progress bar once.

If the situation you have is complex, you'll need to do some pre-calculation to divide up the progress range (and a bit of ratio-oriented math).  But even a crude approximation where the progress bar marches forward at an irregular speed from 0 to 100 is better than having it keep starting over!

Let's say there are three phases. The first takes a minute, the second takes two minutes, and the third takes a half hour. Sure--it would be somewhat strange to see it be 66.6% done after three minutes and then watch it slowly crunch through that last 33.3% for a half hour. But it's not as bad as going back to zero. Also, you should be able to estimate better than that. Even if something varies arbitrarily (such as an early phase reading a number N that can drastically affect a later phase)...can't you scan for that up-front? Allocate the scan maybe 5% of the time, and go from there.

Comment: I take your point; but a QProgressDialog has a QLabel and for each subfunction the text is updated to show what is happening so it does not appear that the same task is starting over at 0%. The reason for my approach is the complexity of dealing with combining the phases. For some of the functions I can predict the time needed and put that in the dialog, but only after the function starts.

Comment: @koan QProgressDialog has a `setLabel()` function so it can be changed while it's running, you do not have to close and reopen it.  Trust me--even if you just guess how much of a range to allocate to each phase, it's an improvement to starting the progress bar over again.  Doing otherwise is based on a *highly flawed belief*.  Namely that somehow, having N progress bars which proceed in a slightly more linear fashion is better than ONE progress bar that  monotonically increases.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function

Comment: As I said above, I update the label text while it is running to show the current subfunction. I can't find anything in the Apple Human Interface Guidelines that say you shouldn't reset progress. There are potentially a massive number of subfunctions that I need to call. I can see value in your view, but as it would take a major rewrite, for now I would prefer to disable the bouncing dock icon.

Comment: @koan The absence of a criticism of a practice in a random document (by a company whose practices, controlling mentality, and litigious culture I have no respect for) does not make it good software design.  That aside... if you insist on ignoring my common sense argument, why aren't you just re-seeking zero and reusing the dialog you have instead of closing and reopening it?  Or turning off autoclose and using reset, I guess:  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprogressdialog.html#reset

Comment: Turning off autoclose was close enough to the result I wanted to achieve. @HostileFork if you submit this as a separate answer then I will accept it. Thanks